# How can I nest a list into sublists of sizes in a given list?

Tags: haskell

I've just started out learning Haskell, and am trying my hand at Project Euler.

I have a list of numbers I'd like to create into a 2-D list split into sublists of lengths defined in another list.

So, I'd like a function which takes a list of Ints and a list of lengths and operates on them like so:

```
f [1..20] [5,8,6] = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13],[14,15,16,17,18,19]]
```

It would be great if the function could take an infinite list of numbers and lengths and just keep sublisting.

I have little idea of how to go about this. Looking around Stack Overflow, I'm seeing (fairly complex to my novice eyes) solutions to packing a list into sublists of equal length, but not much like what I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use recursion to implement the following function according to your specification:

```
splitAts :: [a] -> [Int] -> [[a]]
```

Note that I've flipped the order of arguments, because this way, the partially applied function `splitAts n` can be thought of as the meaningful operation that, given any list, will split it into sublists of the given length.

The easy case is when there are no (more) sublist lengths specified:

```
splitAts [] xs = []
```

The recursive case is when there is some first sublist length `n`: in this case, the first sublist we return will have this length, and the rest will simply be the split of the rest of the list according to the rest of the lengths:

```
splitAts (n:ns) xs = take n xs : splitAts ns (drop n xs)
```

There already exists a function [`splitAt`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:splitAt) that does the `take n` / `drop n` in one sweep, so the above can be rewritten as the better-performing

```
splitAts (n:ns) xs = here : splitAts ns there
  where
    (here, there) = splitAt n xs
```

Example run:

```
*Main> splitAts [5, 8, 6] [1..20]
[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13],[14,15,16,17,18,19]]
```

It is nicely lazy: not just this works:

```
*Main> splitAts [5, 8, 6] [1..]
[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13],[14,15,16,17,18,19]]
```

but this one as well:

```
*Main> take 10 (splitAts [3,5..] [1..])
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24],
[25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35],[36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48]]
```

Comment: I'd rather write `splitAts is xs = snd $ mapAccumL (\xs' i -> swap (splitAt i xs')) xs is`.

Comment: @user3237465 that's a very good point - in real code, use an appropriate recursion scheme combinator instead of hand-coding it.

Comment: I've changed the implementation somewhat to use `splitAt` to avoid traversing the first part of the list twice in `take` and `drop`.

Comment: Can also be written `splitAts ns l = map fst . drop 1 . scanl (\ (_, l') n -> splitAt n l') ([], l) $ ns`